# Можно ли использовать PropTypes для анонимной функции?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Можно ли использовать PropTypes для анонимной функции?
Если можно, то как?

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import ReactIdswiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default memo ( ( { children, params } ) => (
  <ReactIdswiper { ...params }>{ children }</ReactIdswiper>
) );
```

Comment: что такое PropTypes? Что именно ты хочешь с помощью него валидировать?

Comment: @ Grundy это как typescript только для react

Comment: Добавь ссылку на него в вопросе. И все еще непонятно что именно ты бы хотел проверить? Можешь привести пример когда проверка сработала бы и когда нет?

Comment: вопрос *можно ли использовать PropTypes вне реакта*?

Comment: @Август  добавил код

Comment: @Grundy  добавил код

Comment: Как вариант, можно перейти на TS и заменить `propTypes` на интерфейс `typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

проще всего дать имя для этой анонимной функции

```
const Lala =  memo(({ children, params }) => (
  <ReactIdswiper { ...params }>{ children }</ReactIdswiper>
));

Lala.propTypes = {
  что-то_там: PropTypes.string
};

export default Lala;
```

если Вы реально хотите использовать прям анонимную функцию, то используйте `Object.assign`

```
export default Object.assign(
  memo(({ children, params }) => (
      <ReactIdswiper { ...params }>{ children }</ReactIdswiper>
  )),
  { propTypes: { что-то_там: PropTypes.string } }
);
```